# How to output Foreach result in array using array as source PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv

Got a somewhat complicated situation that I have no clue how to get myself out of in PowerShell, and need some help :)

Here's the situation: I have an array generated by importing data from a single-column CSV file (column header: UPN), using `$userId = Import-Csv "Email_List.csv"`

I need to run the command `Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $UserId` on each entry in the $UserId array, and store it in a different array, named $UserObjectID, to be used later.
I can't seem to figure out how to go about this, could somebody help ?

I've tried a few different things, and none of them work :(

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: are you able to post the code you were attempting to execute this with?

Comment: Yes of course: 

`$userId = Import-Csv "Email_List.csv"`
`$appId = "de35f1ae-1805-4a8c-b862-053e75bb94ea"`
`$AzureCreds = Get-Credential`

`Connect-AzureAD -Credential $AzureCreds`
`$user = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $userId`
`$servicePrincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "appId eq '$appId'"`

`New-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $user.ObjectId -PrincipalId $user.ObjectId -ResourceId $servicePrincipal.ObjectId -Id $servicePrincipal.AppRoles.Id`

Comment: Sorry for the fugly formatting, Stack Overflow doesn't allow me to split it on different lines

Comment: @BenH : Tried that already, doesn't work, I get this error `Get-AzureADUser : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'ObjectId'. Specified method is not supported.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps!

In your CSV file you are importing which has the `UserPrincipalName` ***remove*** the `@domain.com.au` and the below will work

```
$UserId = import-csv "\\file\location\Email_List.csv"

$AzureCreds = (Get-Credential)

Connect-AzureAD -Credential $AzureCreds

$appId = "de35f1ae-1805-4a8c-b862-053e75bb94ea" 

Foreach($Name in $UserID.UPN){   
    $user = Get-AzureADUser -SearchString "Name"
    $servicePrincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "appId eq '$appId'" 
    New-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $user.ObjectId -PrincipalId $user.ObjectId -ResourceId $servicePrincipal.ObjectId -Id $servicePrincipal.AppRoles.Id
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!
Just so you know, I had to keep the @domain.com in the csv, because -SearchString acts weird, hence why in my original script, it was pointing to -ObjectID. 
All in all, all I needed was the "foreach [...]" line you added.
With this, I kinda understand a bit more how Foreach works, and I get that I was complicating my life WAY too much haha.

Thanks again for your quick help, saved hours of time! :D